# Filter rows of one dataframe based on string similarity with another dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames of different lengths, let's say A(has more number of rows than B) and B. In both of the data frames, one column is the same ('col1') and the column have string values. The goal is to use Levenshtein distance and if the Levenstein distance is more than a certain threshold then I have to take the rows from A and create a new data frame.

```
Shape of A is 31K x 4
Shape of B is 5K x 9
```

This is the following code I am using to create the new dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import textdistance as td

B_col1_unique_values = list(B['col1'].unique())
new_A_data = []
def compare_vnum(x):
    for idx, vnum in enumerate(B_col1_unique_values):
        if (td.levenshtein.normalized_similarity(str(vnum), str(x)) > 0.90) and (td.jaro_winkler(str(vnum), str(x)) > 0.95):
            B_code = set(B.loc[B['col1']==vnum, 'Code'].tolist())
            A_data = A.loc[(A['Code'].isin(B_code)) & (A['col1'] == x)]
            new_A_data.extend(A_data.values.tolist())

_ = pd.Series(A['col1'].unique()).apply(compare_vnum)
```

Any efficient way I can use to reduce the time of execution?

Comment: The only way of getting a speedup of any significance is vectorizing whatever operation you are performing. The question has nothing to do with pandas. Not sure if a vectorized implementation of Levenshtein distance exists, you may be better off looking at efficient implementations of tf-idf or cosine similarity.